# Gmail - get mailbox delegations in latest API

Tags: gmail-api

I am attempting to get a list of mail delegates for each user within a domain on gmail to display to our users at www.rulerr.com . I am authenticating as a service account with domain wide delegation. I pull a list of users, and then authenticate using the service account as each user in the domain to access their gmail data.

Unfortunately it looks like I cannot access delegation information with the latest API, but the functionality exists in the old (now deprecated) API. When will this functionality be moved to the latest API? Or is there a different endpoint that I should be using?

I have also attempted to work around this by delegating user B's gmail to user A, authenticating as user A and then attempting to list messages within user B's mailbox which results in an error:

`{ [Error: Delegation denied for <email redacted>]
  code: 403,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'forbidden',
       message: 'Delegation denied for <email redacted>' } ] }`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now we will just have to wait for the Gmail API to add the delegation feature from the deprecated [Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/):

> [Managing delegation
>   settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings)
>
> Delegation settings are not yet available via the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply noogui - I am hoping to get some info from Google on when this will be available in the latest API as I don't want to have to implement something that references an API that will be removed later this year.

Comment: We haven't heard announcements yet. Kindly [file a request here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) and hopefully they take notice.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I've added a new feature request.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work on Gmail and the Gmail API platform.*

### Managing Delegation Settings

**We're happy to announce that we have now released the new [Gmail API delegate settings methods](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), effectively replacing the long since [deprecated Email Settings API delegation settings methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings).**

You can now use the standard libraries and tools found at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api to interact with the new Gmail delegate settings methods.

We will be publishing a blog post at https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com raising the visibility of the new delegate settings methods in the coming weeks, but I wanted to personally give you a courtesy heads-up.

#### Documentation

- Overview/introduction guide:
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings
- Reference documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates
- Migration guide (from the deprecated [Email Settings API delegation settings methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_delegation_settings)):
  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/migrate-from-email-settings#managing_delegation_settings